# Why do the values in the listbox just start repeating at a certain point

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am writing a application that populates an array of a user-defined size, with random integers from 1-99. It then displays all of these numbers, with a index predicate, in a listbox. However, when u enter in a length of 10,000 the list box seems to be unable to generate a number greater then 6,000 something and resets back to 3,000 something. Why is this occuring? (Note: i am using Visual Studio 2010)

VB.NET Code:

```
Public Class frmDynamicNumbers

Private Sub btnClick_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClick.Click
    Dim input As String = txtInput.Text
    Dim size As Int64 = 0
    If Not Integer.TryParse(input, size) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a valid number")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim a(size) As Int64
    CreateArray(a)
End Sub

Sub CreateArray(ByRef a As Int64())
    lstDisplay.Items.Clear()
    For i As Int64 = 0 To a.Length - 1
        Dim temp As Int64 = RndInt(1, 99)
        lstDisplay.Items.Add(i.ToString + vbTab + temp.ToString)
    Next
End Sub

Function RndInt(ByVal max As Integer, ByVal min As Integer) As Int64
    Randomize()
    Return Int((max - min + 1) * Rnd()) + min
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Random doesnt mean unique.  The new `Random` class might be a better choice than the legacy VB `Rnd` function: `RNG.Next(1, size+1)` for example.  Are you wanting them to be unique but unordered?

Comment: I was refering to the predicates, which SHOULD work like a MySQL Auto_Increment Column, but they dont

Comment: Cannot repro - the items index is the actual index all the way to 15,000.  Your little RNG is exclusive though, so  the range is actually 2-98